# PHP: included files have wrong encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, include

Strange issue I've faced recently.
I've developed a little plain-php website engine. All possible encoding configurations are set properly (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` and apache virtualhost bits as well, so content type http headers are correct).
What's wrong then?
Everything in php file that is accessed (e.g. index.php) is displaying properly.
But the contents that is included from external files is displayed as question marks.
[image]

see? the middle frame is generated by index.php and it's ok, but top menubar is generated by included file. if I move menubar routine to index.php it also looks good.

Comment: What encoding are those files saved in...?!

Comment: yes, I forgot to say that. everything is saved properly in UTF-8. it's more strange, because it all works as designed on production hosting. the issue orccures on my developement environment

Comment: >> included from external files ... hint: check the coding of the external files, if they are also utf8

Comment: @donald123: thanks for suggestion but look at my comment above

Comment: sorry didn't see it while writing ... what is the meaning of >>developement environment<<? how does you include the external files? can you post the relevant code of your index.php

Comment: If it looks okay when you move the include file code inside the index.php it seems that perhaps the included file is in Russian instead of UTF-8 ?

Comment: @Jack Russian is a language. UTF-8 is an encoding. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: try to set encoding using ini_set(),hopes this works..!!

Comment: @deceze Yeah I knew that actually ... I meant to say it's not in a utf8 compatible character set :)

Answer (score 0):

If it works on production environment, it may be a server misconfiguration.

First, try to retrieve the file included in production environment to check if the issue comes from here. It may indeed be an encoding problem. Ensure there are encoded in UTF-8 (ideally without BOM). Notepad++ has a feature to convert a file from an encoding to another.

Secondly, try to add (if not already done: if it sends HTTP headers correctly, it should already been here) the following line to your Apache configuration:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Do not forget to restart your Apache server.

Let us know if it works. :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your files in windows notebook
2. Change file type to ALL FILE TYPES
3. Change encoding to UTF-8
4. Save your file
5. Try again! :O)